# Django ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor.__set__ ValueError

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-contenttypes

I am creating a custom data migration to automatically create GenericRelation entries in the database, based on existing entries across two different models.

**Example models.py:**

```
...
class Place
   content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
   object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


class Restaurant
   name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class House
   location = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

**Example 0011_place_data.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models, migrations

def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    Restaurant = apps.get_model("simpleapp", "Restaurant")
    House = apps.get_model("simpleapp", "House")
    Place = apps.get_model("simpleapp", "Place")

    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias

    content_type = ContentType.objects.using(db_alias).get(
        app_label="simpleapp",
        model="restaurant"
    )

    for restaurant in Restaurant.objects.using(db_alias).all():
        Place.objects.using(db_alias).create(
            content_type=content_type,
            object_id=restaurant.id)

    content_type = ContentType.objects.using(db_alias).get(
        app_label="simpleapp",
        model="house"
    )
    for house in House.objects.using(db_alias).all():
        Place.objects.using(db_alias).create(
            content_type=content_type,
            object_id=house.id)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('simpleapp', '0010_place')
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            forwards_func,
        ),
    ]
```

When I run this (Django 1.7.4) I get

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: simpleapp, admin, sessions, auth, contenttypes
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying projects.0011_place_data...passing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 108, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 117, in database_forwards
self.code(from_state.render(), schema_editor)
  File ".../simpleapp/migrations/0011_place_data.py", line 19, in forwards_func
object_id=restaurant.id)
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 370, in create
obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 440, in __init__
setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 598, in __set__
self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "<ContentType: restaurant>": "Place.content_type" must be a "ContentType" instance.
```

If I comment out the stanza raising the value error in the Django module (django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor.**set**) it works as expected:

```
...

    elif value is not None and not isinstance(value, self.field.rel.to):
        print('skipping')
        #raise ValueError(
        #    'Cannot assign "%r": "%s.%s" must be a "%s" instance.' % (
        #        value,
        #        instance._meta.object_name,
        #        self.field.name,
        #        self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name,
        #    )
        #)

...
```

Should this exception be raised in the first place? Is this a bug in Django or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: i don't understand what you are commenting out. And please can you show the *full* traceback?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:

The solution below does not actually work; it just ends up not running the forwards_func so there are no errors. New solutions welcome:

---

I was able to resolve this using [Django's post_migrate signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#post-migrate).

This also fixes some other issues that arrive from these types of migrations (data migrations which reference the ContentType table).

My understanding is that essentially, the issue is the ContentType table doesn't get created until the very end of a migration for performance reasons. This means I'm not actually retrieving the same type ContentType object that the relation module is checking for.

The solution is to run this type of data migration as a callback:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models, migrations

def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    Restaurant = apps.get_model("simpleapp", "Restaurant")
    House = apps.get_model("simpleapp", "House")
    Place = apps.get_model("simpleapp", "Place")

    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias

    def add_stuffs(*args, **kwargs)
        content_type = ContentType.objects.using(db_alias).get(
            app_label="simpleapp",
            model="restaurant"
        )

        for restaurant in Restaurant.objects.using(db_alias).all():
            Place.objects.using(db_alias).create(
                content_type=content_type,
                object_id=restaurant.id)

        content_type = ContentType.objects.using(db_alias).get(
            app_label="simpleapp",
            model="house"
        )
        for house in House.objects.using(db_alias).all():
            Place.objects.using(db_alias).create(
               content_type=content_type,
               object_id=house.id)

    post_migrate.connect(add_stuffs)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('simpleapp', '0010_place')
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            forwards_func,
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's somewhat related to this Django [bug/wontfix](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23422)

I had similar error when tried to re-assign permissions to user groups in my migration. To fix it I had to manually emit post_migrate signal as described [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23422#comment:25)

Here is my migration code example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations
from django.core.management.sql import emit_post_migrate_signal


def trigger_post_migrate(db_alias):
    try:
        # Django 1.9
        emit_post_migrate_signal(2, False, db_alias)
    except TypeError:
        # Django < 1.9
        try:
            # Django 1.8
            emit_post_migrate_signal(2, False, 'default', db_alias)
        except TypeError:
            # Django < 1.8
            emit_post_migrate_signal([], 2, False, 'default', db_alias)


def up(apps, schema_editor):
    # trigger post migrate to make sure all permissions and contenttypes are in place
    trigger_post_migrate(schema_editor.connection.alias)

    # migration code here...


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0008_auto_20160712_0608'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(up),
    ]
```